# Remove TFS references from my console application

Tags: tfs

I inadvertently added my new console application to TFS (I didn't even check it in) and now it tries to connect to TFS when I open the solution.

What do I need to remove TFS references from my console application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open up your solution (.sln) file in notepad. Remove the section that has references to Scc like below

```
GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution
    SccNumberOfProjects = 2
    SccEnterpriseProvider = {4CA58AB2-18FA-4F8D-95D4-32DDF27D184C}
    SccTeamFoundationServer = http://mytfs:8080/tfs/ieb
    SccLocalPath0 = .
    SccProjectUniqueName1 = ConsoleApp3\\ConsoleApp3.csproj
    SccProjectName1 = ConsoleApp3
    SccLocalPath1 = ConsoleApp3
EndGlobalSection
```

Also, remove the .vssscc file from the directory where your Solution (.sln) file directory.